# Auto Generate @String reference in Android Studio for all hardcoded strings

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources

When I started coding my project I did not know the string resource. Now I would like to use this resource for all my string. How do you do it all of a sudden? Knowing that I have more than 10000 strings currently I do not want to do it one by one by hand ...

Answer (score 2):

To automate this completely you need a special tool (I haven't found one), outside of Android Studio to:

- Find the string (and replace with the reference)
- Update strings.xml
- optionally translate strings

For one at a time manual extract (See also [link](http://envyandroid.com/android-studio-extract-strings-resources/)):
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, **Extract String Resource** while the caret is inside the hardcoded string in **code**:

[image: extract]
and in **XML**:
[image: extract]

Comment: i find this one but I do not know how to install it. [https://github.com/constantine-ivanov/strings-xml-tools](https://github.com/constantine-ivanov/strings-xml-tools)

Comment: Comments from this link suggest this plugin does not work anymore   https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7498

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, that there is a slink workaround considering, that you need to name all string somehow with a unique and useful identifier. When you let this be done automatically, your code will get quite hard to read :/

Comment: Would there be a means of making them one after the other?

Answer (score 0):

Just highlight every instance of a string,then click on the yellow hint icon on the left of the statemnt to extract string resource.Then you can remove duplicated strings later.

Comment: How to highlight every instances ?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a java script for xml layouts at least, for anyone who needs it... There might be some minor fixes required later.

```
package com.cameron.smelevel.lib;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

    public class StringResourceCreator {


    public static void main(String [] args){
        String mainDirPath = "S:\\androidProject\\src";
        String layoutDirPath = "\\main\\res\\layout";
        String outputDirPath = mainDirPath+"-out";
        String stringFilePath = outputDirPath+"\\strings.txt";
        String line;

        File layoutDir = new File(mainDirPath + layoutDirPath);
        File layoutOutDir = new File(outputDirPath + layoutDirPath);
        layoutOutDir.mkdirs();
        HashMap<String, String> stringEnteries = new HashMap<>();
        for (File file : layoutDir.listFiles()) {
            String fileName = file.getName();
            PrintWriter pr = null;
            try {
                // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
                FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);

                // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
                FileWriter outputStream = new FileWriter(layoutOutDir.getAbsolutePath() + "\\"+ fileName);
                pr = new PrintWriter(outputStream);

                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    line = getModifiedLine(line, stringEnteries);
                    pr.write(line);
                    pr.println();
                }
            } catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
                System.out.println("Unable to open file '" + fileName + "'");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error reading file '" + fileName + "'");
                // Or we could just do this:
                // ex.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                if(pr != null) pr.close();
            }
        }
        PrintWriter pr = null;
        try {
            FileWriter outputStream = new FileWriter(stringFilePath);
            pr = new PrintWriter(outputStream);

            Iterator it = stringEnteries.entrySet().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
                String entry = "<string name=\"" + pair.getKey() + "\">" + pair.getValue() + "</string>";
                it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException

                pr.write(entry);
                pr.println();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            if(pr != null) pr.close();
        }
    }

    private static String getModifiedLine(String line, HashMap<String, String> stringEnteries) {
        if (line.contains(":text=\"") || line.contains(":hint=\"")){
            StringBuilder fieldName = new StringBuilder();
            String text = line.substring(line.indexOf("\"")+1, line.lastIndexOf("\""));
            String textTrimmed = text.replace("\\n","");
            if (!textTrimmed.startsWith("@string")){
                String[] words = textTrimmed.split(" ");
                for (int j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
                    String word = words[j];
                    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
                        char c = word.charAt(i);
                        if (Character.isAlphabetic(c))
                            if (i == 0 && fieldName.length() != 0)
                                fieldName.append(Character.toUpperCase(c));
                            else
                                fieldName.append(Character.toLowerCase(c));
                    }
                }
                if (fieldName.length() > 1) {
                    String value = stringEnteries.get(fieldName.toString());
                    if(value != null) {
                        if (!value.equals(text)) {
                            fieldName.append("1");
                            stringEnteries.put(fieldName.toString(), text);
                        }
                    }else
                        stringEnteries.put(fieldName.toString(), text);

                    line = line.replace(text, "@string/"+fieldName);//replaceLast(line, text, "@string/"+fieldName);
                }
            }
        }
        return line;
    }

}
```